# Installing a HP Envy 5530 printer

Tags: printing

I have purchased a HP Envy 5530 printer. How do I install it with only Ubuntu as the operating system?

HP printers can only be installed using Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 2):

The printer is supported. Use the HP Tools or the CUPS web interface

### CUPS web interface

Connect your printer, open the URL http://localhost:631/admin in your browser and click <kbd>Add Printer</kbd>

[image]

---

### HP Tools

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

Connect your printer, start <kbd>HPLIP Toolbox</kbd> and add your printer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go from browser to http://localhost:631/ -> Adding Printers and Classes -> Add Printer